# change liquid syntax into nunjucks - is this correct?

Tags: liquid, nunjucks, eleventy

I need to change this liquid syntax into nunjucks:

```
{% assign posts = collections.post | getPostsByContributor: contributor.key %}
```

Is this correct for nunjucks?

```
{% set posts = collections.post | getPostsByContributor: contributor.key %}
```

Eleventy gives me error "expected block end in set statement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for passing arguments to Nunjucks filters is a bit different. Try this:

```
{% set posts = collections.post | getPostsByContributor(contributor.key) %}
```

More info:

- [Docs for Liquid filters](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/#filters)
- [Docs for Nunjucks filters](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#filters)

Comment: @rocco Great! Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I see. I have now accepted your answer. I wanted also to vote it, but it says "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote,"